# Two Paragraphs/Divs inline

Tags: css, html, inline

Hi there I am not sure how to go about a particular problem so here it is.
Without using a Table I would like to display a paragraph with multiply lines of text then have an image on the right.

So far I have tried this:

```
<div id="container">
 <p>
  Some Text
  Some Text
  Some Text
  Some Text
 </p>
 <p>
 <img src="image.jpg"/>
 </p>
</div>
```

I use a separate stylesheet
and have tried such things as display inline with no luck.

I will be grateful for any suggestions although I do not want to use a table as I am not a fan of using tables for layout.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need another set of containers indie your container:

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
<p>...<p/>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:50%">
<p>...<p/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you may consider using flexbox (which is fairly well supported now : https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox )

You just need to make your container a display : flex; (example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvZYwj)

```
#container { 
  display: flex;
}
```

For more infos about flexbox you can start out by reading MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes.

And if you want to get more about flexbox, there is this amazing tutorial :  http://flexboxzombies.com/p/flexbox-zombies

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're wanting to do.  You could give the

tag a class/style and do float:right in the CSS.  Which would look like this:

```
<p style="float:right;"><img src="image.jpg" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yo want text flow around image? If yes then it is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2FMPf/1/

If you want separate column for image, then it is something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2FMPf/2/

Comment: It seems that no matter what I try it can't be done without using a table. using float no matter if I float to the left or right produces some weird layouts with the rest of my css for example it always leaves a line above the text or image and positioning becomes difficult

Comment: Thanks for all the excellent suggestions but each one comes with complications it seems that what I am trying to do which I think I haven't explained correctly can't be done without a table.